# How to change multiple language for Android App?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to change the language for my android app, however I could not do it.

I used `string.xml` to add my text and called it in my text views in my activities.

However, I have so many text Views.

I need to create as many string names or is there any possibilty to change if i add some text views.

I have so many textViews and also so many activities.

Please guide me.

I used string.xml to add my text and called it in my text views in my activities.

Comment: _"I used string.xml to add my text and called it in my text views in my activities."_ Sounds like the right way. It's also possible to use parameters in the strings if you have strings that share a common static part and a varying dynamic part.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be using `sharedPrefrences`, (specially in case of only two languages);

1. Create your source of `String`s in both languages. Do it anyway you like.
2. Create the UI which user will use it to change the language. By this `View` you should change the value of the respected `sharedPreference`. The values would be "languageOne" and "languageTwo", or booleans.
3. In all `textViews`, `editTexts`, and etc set the text like this: `view.setText(sharedPreferenceValue.equals("languageOne")?"theStringInLanguageOne":"theStringInLanguageTwo");`

Comment: Thank you. I started trying this. I will confirm once its done. Since, I am not a learned coder: I am trying all this with my own interest.

Comment: Why make it the wrong way when there's a right way? If you do it like this and want to add a third language, you need to go trough all the code and rewrite all the conditions. But if you do it the right way, you just add one more `strings.xml`.

Comment: Dear @MarkusKauppinen, I've already mentioned that "_One way could be using..._".
I'll also limit my answer to two languages within an edit . . .